# posting rows of html table separately to php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to store contents a tr in table #itemsTable,  in array celValues and post it to php and repeat it (post next tr until last tr).
here is code:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    //alert("hi");
    var celValues= new Array();
    $('#itemsTable tr').each(function() {
           celValues[0] = $('td:nth-child(2)').find('input').val();
           celValues[1] = $('td:nth-child(3)').find('input').val();
           celValues[2] = $('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val();
           celValues[3] = $('td:nth-child(5)').find('input').val();
           celValues[4] = $('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val();

           $.post("test.php", {celvalues: celValues},function(data){

                 document.write(data);

           });

    }); 

});
```

test.php:

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  $arr= array();
  $arr = $_POST['celvalues'];
  foreach($arr as $val)
         {
             echo " " .$arr[$i];
             $i++; 
         }
?>
```

problem is it repeats first row instead of posting contents of all tr.

output for 3 row with different contents.but first row repeated 3 times:

1000 Website Design 1 100.5 100.5 1000Website Design1100.5100.5 1000 Website Design 1 100.5 100.5

Comment: Double check that foreach loop, you're printing out `$arr` instead of `$val`. Also, a good debugging technique is to use `print_r($array)` to see the raw contents of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there doesn't seem to be a point in your code for iterating through the trs because you're not utilizing them

perhaps you meant

```
 $('#itemsTable tr').each(function(index, element) {
           celValues[0] = $(element).find('td:nth-child(2)').find('input').val();
           celValues[1] = $(element).find('td:nth-child(3)').find('input').val();

....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#save').click(function(){  
           $.post("test.php", {form: $("#yourFromID").serialize()},function(data){
                 document.write(data);
           });   
});
```

in test.php

```
<?php
  $i=0;
  $arr= array();
  $arr = $_POST['form'];
  foreach($arr as $val)
         {
             echo " " .$arr[$i];
             $i++; 
         }
?>
```

in response to your comment here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/TtCLQ/8/) the serialized form will have the values for all input fields

Comment: I want to post each tr separately in order to save it in database.